# Iterating over a list in python

Tags: python

I'm very new to python and would like some insight on what i'm doing wrong...

I have the following code:

```
import csv

csv_file = "my_file.csv"

with open(csv_file) as csvDataFile:
    csvReader = csv.reader(open(csv_file, 'rU'), dialect=csv.excel_tab)
    for row in csvReader:
        elements = row[0].split(',')
        var1 = elements[0];
        var2 = elements[1];
        var3 = elements[2];
        var4 = elements[3];
        newString = 'http://website.com?';
        newString + 'var1='+var1;
        newString + 'var2='+var2;
        print(newString);
```

This code iterates through each line of my csv file and splits each column by comma. I would like to reference the elements in the resulting list by an index (i.e. 0, 1, 2, 3). I don't want to iterate over the resulting list... I would prefer to concatenate them together in a string.

Anyone know how this can be done in python?

Comment: WHat issue are you seeing with elements[0]? This looks like it should be right

Comment: why are you `open(csv_file)` twice? You never actually use `csvDataFile` from your context-manager, defeating the entire purpose

Comment: **why** would you prefer to reference each element by index?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga i'm trying to concatenate the columns (or elements) together into another string

Comment: @BobbyBruce yes, so? And what about `elements[0]` isn't working? **what exactly is your problem**?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Sorry, for some reason trying to concatenate it to a string does not work. `myString = "col1="; myString + elements[0];`

Comment: Look, you *need to put more effort into explaining your problem*. "it doesn't work" is not an adequate problem statement. *How does it not work*?

Comment: @BobbyBruce That's a completely different issue. If `elements[0]` is not of type `str` then concatenation wont work.

Comment: @BobbyBruce You need to update your question with the overall problem you are trying to solve. Currently, you can access `elements` by index with no problem. Your choice to iterate over it with a `for` is your choice for whatever you have chosen.

Comment: Sorry guys - I have revised my question to more accurately describe what I am trying to do. Being new to python, I honestly didn't know _how_ to ask to the question. Hopefully the revision helps.

Comment: @BobbyBruce Your edit is fine for your purpose. The only thing to be careful about is the type when concatenating. If any of the `var` are not `str` the concatenation will fail.

Comment: @BobbyBruce You need to remove `;` that is not a thing in Python. Also, your final `newString` should be `newString = "http://website.com?" + var1 + var2`. Again, assuming each `var` is of type `str`.

Comment: @BobbyBruce You should show what you want your desired output to look like. As has been said, you can access elements without iteration already.

Comment: Why wouldn't they be strings coming out of a text csv file?